# visual c++: how to pass pointer to array as parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

The code below shown is in visual c++

```
array<Byte>^ b = gcnew array <Byte> (filesize);
fs->Read(b,0,b->Length);
unsigned char *pb;
pb=(byte*)malloc(b->Length);    //pb is unmanaged here.

for(int i=0;i<b->Length;i++)
{
     *(pb+i)=InverseByte(b+i);
}
```

I want to call the function below to reverse each byte. How can I do this?
I want to do inverse of each byte of managed array b, and put it in the unmanaged array b.

```
unsigned char InverseByte(unsigned char* PbByte)
{
    //something;
}
```

Comment: So do you want to flip the bits in each byte, rearrange the bits in each byte, or rearrange the bytes in the array?

Comment: if a byte is 11110010, then it should be 01001111

Comment: OK, but the question in your message body doesn't have anything to do with the question in the title.

Comment: My question is how to send pointer to array. I tried **InverseByte(&b[0])**. But it did not work.

Comment: How did it not work? I'm still not sure what the problem is. Do you have a situation where you absolutely need to have the address of a managed array element? This is not such a situation.

Answer (score 3):

Fix the declaration of InverseByte:

```
unsigned char InverseByte(unsigned char value)
```

So you can then use it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < b->Length; i++)
{
    pb[i] = InverseByte(b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean bitwise negation I presume.

```
unsigned char InverseByte(unsigned char c)
{
    return ~c;
}
```

Note that I changed the parameter to pass by value rather than passing a pointer to the value.

I also fail to see why you are using pointer arithmetic instead of indexing. That just makes your code harder to read. The loop should be written like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<b->Length;i++)
{      
    pb[i] = InverseByte(b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char InverseByte(unsigned char c)
{
    return (c>>7)|((c&64)>>5)|((c&32)>>3)|((c&16)>>1)|((c&8)<<1)|((c&4)<<3)|((c&2)<<5)|((c&1)<<7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it's clear you are **reversing** the bytes (i.e. reordering them front-to-back) rather than **inverting** (i.e. subtracting a variable from its maximum value) or **negating** (i.e. flipping 1's and 0's), so should name the function accordingly.

Here's a [neat little snippet](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious) from Seander's bithacks:

```
   unsigned int v;     // input bits to be reversed
   unsigned int r = v; // r will be reversed bits of v; first get LSB of v
   int s = sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT - 1; // extra shift needed at end

   for (v >>= 1; v; v >>= 1)
   {   
       r <<= 1;
       r |= v & 1;
       s--;
   }

   r <<= s; // shift when v's highest bits are zero
   return r;
```

If you combine Hans Passant's answer with this, you should have all the pieces to put together your function.